# LDAP: use of attributes in an application

Tags: active-directory, ldap, acl, openldap

This a theoretical question about usage of directory services (DS) in applications. I dont care if it is ActiveDirectory, OpenLDAP, ... but I suggest the LDAP-protocol.
And I am new to the topic of DS so please excuse my simple question.

Most of the time I think applications use the authentication-mechanism only. Pass the credentials that the user puts in the applications login-dialog to the ldap-bind and see if it works.

But I'd like to understand how to design and implement application-internal access-rights within a DS - not only authentication for a login. So e.g. to check if a user is allowed to click a button.

Is it just the query of an created LDAP-object and check its attribute-value (that has only a meaning in the application that reads it) against an expected value that indicates a pass or a deny?
Thats pretty simple and I am not sure thats all of the miracle...

Is it?

P.S.: I am not talking about enterprise features of a DS (replication, perforance, ...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the time I think applications use the authentication-mechanism only. Pass the credentials that the user puts in the applications login-dialog to the ldap-bind and see if it works.

They certainly do that, but there's more.

> But I'd like to understand how to design and implement application-internal access-rights within a DS - not only authentication for a login. So e.g. to check if a user is allowed to click a button.

After authentication, applications will then retrieve attributes of the user, or DNs in which his own DN appear, such as roles.

> Is it just the query of an created LDAP-object and check its attribute-value (that has only a meaning in the application that reads it) against an expected value that indicates a pass or a deny? Thats pretty simple and I am not sure thats all of the miracle...

How this is done depends on how exactly roles are represented in your LDAP server. You've described one way: there are others.

Answer (score 1):

EJP summarizes about everything.

But one point I'd like to enhance is :

> Is it just the query of an created LDAP-object and check its attribute-value ...

As EJP said, you can do it this way. DS is in my opinion a restriction on what LDAP implementation server can do. A DS is, imho, a hierarchical object oriented database. And so you can store roles, users, and rules/relations between those.

But there are more, and for the point you mentioned, there is one in particular that I really appreciate, is the ACL mechanism.

I know the OpenLDAP implementation, so I will take it as an exmaple, but I'm sure others have same mechanisms.

The ACL allows you to describe inside the DS what a user can have access to with different rights :

- read
- write
- execute
- ...

So you can easily imagine a branch in the DS which describes your application, and configure the ACL to allow certain groups of users to have different access to the entries corresponding to the application.

In practical use, you will be able to search the application branch and all its childs, and the DS will return you only the branches/entries/attributes of the entries that you are able to read.

This is something I have imagined sometime for different applications, but never pushed it to this extrem, so this needs to be thought more to optimize it, but it is feasible.

What I usually do is, for example, your DS contains a branch of stores, and according to the roles of your user, not every attribute of a store are readable/writable, so I implement this mechnism in the ACL and in actual code, I just :

- retrieve the store : the attribute the user can't read are not returned
- write changes to the store : if the user can't write a certain attribute, the DS will return an error.

So all the access right logic is "built in" the DS and you just have to manage a CRUD api.

Comment: That last part is very good for my question. It is much more elegant than reading and interpreting. As you said the rights-logic is kept in the DS.